# How to convert %Y-%M format to date in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe column that has dates in this format : %Y-%M when I check the type, it is character.
I still get the fortmat "%Y-%M-%D even when I try to convert it into a date type using the following code :

```
df$dates <- as.Date(df$Month_Yr, "%Y-%M")
```

How can I get my date in the right format AND date type because I don't know how to get both, Thank you!

Here is some of my data

```
    dates      Country Specie median         Month-Yr
1   2014-12-29  AT  co    0.1                2014-06
2   2014-12-29  AT  no2   15.780000000000001 2014-06
3   2014-12-29  AT  pm10  20.8               2014-06
4   2014-12-29  AT  pm25  69.5               2014-06
5   2014-12-29  AT  so2   2.0                2014-06
6   2014-12-29  AU  co    2.3333333333333335 2014-06
7   2014-12-29  AU  neph  6.333333333333333  2014-06
8   2014-12-29  AU  no2   4.314285714285714  2014-06
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of your data?

Comment: yes, just edited it!

Comment: Try: `zoo::as.yearmon(df$Month_Yr)`

Comment: To complement @GKi comments, you can use zoo to convert to date from yearmon. `zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(df$Month_Yr))`

Comment: @KostasVasilopoulos For this you don't need `zoo`. You can use `as.Date(paste0(df$Month_Yr, "-01"))`

Comment: @GKi True, your answer works. I just wanted to point out the `as.yearmon` returns an object of class `yearmon` and not a `Date`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked